# Error: "An issue happened while applying the transaction". Grafbase problem on production

Tags: reactjs, next.js, graphql, next-auth

When I try to create a server I get an error. The server is created but without any relation to the user. Everything works fine locally. The error only appears in production.
Here's my schemas:

```
schema
  @auth(
    providers: [
      { type: jwt, issuer: "nextauth", secret: "{{ env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET }}" }
    ]
    rules: [{ allow: private }]
  ) {
  query: Query
}

type User @model {
  name: String!
  email: Email! @unique
  password: String
  servers: [Server]
}

type Server @model {
  name: String!
  createdBy: User! @relation(name: "creator")
  users: [User]!
}
```

And the query:

```
mutation ServerCreate {
  serverCreate(
    input: {
      name: "server 1"
      createdBy: {
        link: "user_01HC7EKE3RX5GPTX9764V8C0TH"
      }
      users: [{
        link: "user_01HC7EKE3RX5GPTX9764V8C0TH"
      }]
    }
  ) {
    server {
      name
      createdBy {
        name
      }
      id
      users(first: 10) {
        edges {
          node {
            name
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The problem only appears in production, so it may be a configuration problem.